# Netbeans C++ not finding standard libraries (Macintosh)

Tags: c++, macos, netbeans

I am trying to use Netbeans 6.7 (on a Mac) to create C++ applications. I started out with the standard "Hello World," just to test if everything was working correctly. First try std and  could not be found. So I tried reinstalling the developer tools on my Mac OS X disk. After that Netbeans updated its c++ compiler info, but still cannot find `std` or `<iostream>`. Odder than this XCode seems to be working with C++ perfectly fine.

Any help fixing this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify, you did do something akin to: `#include <iostream> int main(){ std::cout << "Sup." << std::endl; }` right?

Comment: Yes, first i tried using namespace std; then i tried std::cout << "Hello, World!\n"; 

Neither works, both are giving me the error "Unable to resolve identifier std"

Comment: Your header matched mine? (no .h?) In any case, perhaps a re-install is necessary. I don't know Mac OS tools at all.

Comment: @GMan: It was exactly as I posted, no .h. Thanks for the help, i think i will do a reinstall

Comment: Yup no problem. I've done all I can. :P

Answer (score 0):

XCode's install scripts are a mess. It doesn't always put things in the right places, and in this case it sounds like the libs got misplaced as well. If you can't find them in /usr/lib or /usr/local/lib, your options from here are update to Lion and use the latest version of XCode and/or download a snapshot of the C++ Standard Lib from Apache or GNU and build it yourself.

(since this is an old question I'm posting for people who have stumbled here from Google)

Comment: In this case I think it might be helpful to include that at the time of posting this question I was running OS X 10.6 and the issue was completely resolved upgrading to Lion with a developer tools reinstall.